# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/tmplib/libVisionProxy.so: /tmp/tmplib/libVisionProxy.so

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, testng, sikuli

I am running Testng with Sikuli script, it is working fine in Eclipse ide.
In Eclipse IDE I am using Java 1.7.0 version.

But when I created an Ant script it is throwing an exception.
When I checked with ant -v

Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on September 8 2010
Buildfile: build.xml
Detected Java version: 1.6 --->(I need Java 1.7 version)
Detected OS: Linux
[antlib:org.apache.tools.ant] Could not load definitions from resource org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.
 [property] Loading Environment env.
Build sequence for target(s) `build' is [init, build]
Complete build sequence is [init, build, clean, compile, run, jar, usage, makexsltreports, all, create-jar, runTestNG, ]

init:
     [echo] start.time

build:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds

I have to use Java 1.7

When I run ant.

ant run

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/tmplib/libVisionProxy.so: /tmp/tmplib/libVisionProxy.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1755)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1651)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:787)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1022)
    at com.wapmx.nativeutils.jniloader.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLoader.java:44)
    at org.sikuli.script.Finder.(Finder.java:33)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region.doFind(Region.java:1029)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region$RepeatableFind.run(Region.java:1232)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region$Repeatable.repeat(Region.java:1203)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region.wait(Region.java:497)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region.find(Region.java:381)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region.getLocationFromPSRML(Region.java:1129)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region.click(Region.java:606)
    at org.sikuli.script.Region.click(Region.java:593)
    at Sample_Test.launchApplication(Sample_Test.java:74)
    at Sample_Test.test1(Sample_Test.java:330)
... Removed 24 stack frames

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7
```

or wherever you installed java7 before running ant for your java version problem. It should handle the 64/32 bits problem as well as 1 of your java version seems to be a 32bit install on a 64bit architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it has something to do with that your java version is a 64 bit installation rather than a 32 bit installation. I'm not entirely sure though. Either that or Grooveek's suggestion. :)